# Centrally specify dates to not land on

Tags: javascript, date

I have the following piece of Javascript in that display a future date. Is there a way i can specify a list of days (WET) for it to not land on? So for example, if the date lands on Christmas, have it automatically + 1 (providing it's still a business day and not another holiday)?

Here's what I'm working with:

```js
function addDates(startDate,noOfDaysToAdd){
  var count = 0;
  while(count < noOfDaysToAdd){
    endDate = new Date(startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 1));
    if(endDate.getDay() != 0 && endDate.getDay() != 6){
       //Date.getDay() gives weekday starting from 0(Sunday) to 6(Saturday)
       count++;
    }
  }
  return startDate;
}

function convertDate(d) {
  function pad(s) { return (s < 10) ? '0' + s : s; }
  return [pad(d.getDate()), pad(d.getMonth()+1), d.getFullYear()].join('/');
}


var today = new Date();
var daysToAdd = 6;
var endDate = addDates(today,daysToAdd);
document.write(convertDate(endDate));
```

Comment: You probably need a list of days for it to not land on, then compare the future date and if it matches, move it forward by a day, compare again, etc. What have you tried? The *addDates* function looks suspect to me, the entire function can be `startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + noOfDaysToAdd)`. The comparison of *getDay* is unnecessary and probably wrong.

Comment: That's pretty much what I'm hoping to get. Are you able to provide some code by any chance? I'm pretty new to Javascript

Answer (score 0):

Adding days to a Date is covered in [*Add days to JavaScript Date*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/add-days-to-javascript-date).

To avoid weekends (assuming Saturday and Sunday, some places use different days like Thursday and Friday) you can check the result and move forward if the day is 6 (Saturday) or 0 (Sunday). Similarly you can check for holidays using formatted date strings (easier than using Date objects).

A simple algorithm is to add the required days to a date, then if it lands on a weekend or holiday, keep adding days one at a time until it doesn't.

```js
// Utility functions
// Add days to a date
function addDays(date, days) {
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
  return date;
}

// Return true if date is Sat or Sun
function isWeekend(date) {
  return date.getDay() == 0 || date.getDay() == 6;
}

// Return true if date is in holidays
function isHoliday(date) {
  return holidays.indexOf(formatISOLocal(date)) != -1;
}

// Show formatted date
function showDate(date) {
  return date.toLocaleString(undefined, {
    weekday:'long',
    day: 'numeric',
    month: 'long',
    year: 'numeric'
  });
}

// Return date string in YYYY-MM-DD format
function formatISOLocal(d) {
  function z(n){return (n<10? '0':'')+n}
  return d.getFullYear() + '-' + z(d.getMonth()+1) + '-' + z(d.getDate());
}

// Main function
// Special add days to avoid both weekends and holidays
function specialAddDays(date, days) {

  // Add days
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
  
  // While date is a holiday or weekened, keep adding days
  while (isWeekend(date) || isHoliday(date)) {
    addDays(date, 1);
  }
  return date;
}

// Holidays      Tuesday      Wednesday     Eid al-Adha   Christmas
var holidays = ['2017-08-22','2017-08-23', '2017-09-01', '2017-12-25'];

// Examples
var d = new Date(2017,7,18,1,30);
console.log('Start day: ' + showDate(d)); // Friday
specialAddDays(d, 1);
console.log('Day added: ' + showDate(d)); // Monday

// Tue and Wed are (fake) holidays, so should return Thursday
specialAddDays(d, 1);
console.log('Day added: ' + showDate(d));
```